# another "SSH connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number"

Tags: ssh, git, github

I have a problem with my first-time SSH connection. Yes, I've already done your guides, already tried your "Dealing with firewalls and proxies" article and the problem is still occuring. I am using Win7 32bit, Windows Firewall is disabled, haven't any third-party firewalls, ESET Nod32 Antivirus is not blocking any ports, I am not using any proxy (neither local proxy).

Here goes the logs:

1. Ordinary SSH connection try

   ```
   C:\Users\Mariusz>ssh -vvv git@github.com
   OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
   debug1: connect to address 207.97.227.239 port 22: Not owner
   ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
   ```
2. NCAT connection try

   ```
   C:\Users\Mariusz>ncat github.com 22
   Strange connect error from 207.97.227.239 (10013): No error
   10013 = WSAEACCES
   ```

   I think that the "smart-http-support" method won't work for me because I haven't created a repo yet.
   I have just done `git init` locally, and stopped at the `git push` step, which returns the same error:

   ```
   ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
   ```
3. corkscrew method (first article from your guide)

   While PUTTYing (with pageant in bg), after inputing login - an error is occuring (MessageBox):

   ```
   Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
   ```

   And in the terminal this message is printed out:

   ```
   Server refused our key
   ```

I have generated the key correctly, using `ssh-keygen`.

I tried not method by editing `~/.ssh/config` yet because I had thought that because I haven't pushed anything to my remote repo so I won't be able to clone anything.

The SSH-forwarding method will not work for me, because it "requires access to an external SSH server" and I haven't any at this time.

What else could I do?

Comment: Note: “your guides” seems to refer to [some GitHub documents](http://help.github.com/firewalls-and-proxies/). I guess this post was initially part of a GitHub support request and was just copy and pasted into SO.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Smart HTTP method.  Just follow the second example in the [instructions](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support) and use push instead of clone.  For instance:

```
git push https://mariusz@github.com/mariusz/project.git
```

It works for all `git` commands that involve remote repositories.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the asker has some network issues with SSH; HTTP-based access is probably the best idea. @Mariusz: With GitHub, “smart HTTP” access is a drop-in replacement for SSH-based access (as long as you have Git 1.6.6 or later on your end). Just use the `https://github.com/user/repo.git` URL instead of `git@github:user/repo.git` (e.g. in your remote configuration).

Comment: can this technique be made to work for github gists too?

Comment: @Mark:  It appears GitHub doesn't support HTTP for Gist at all.  I couldn't even clone a Gist repository over it.